# How to use value element as a key of second element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

i have json like below:

```js
[{"id":19,"text":"A-Z CLI 19/03/2015"},{"id":36,"text":"Wavetel Retail1"},{"id":37,"text":"Wavetel A2Z Platinum"},{"id":38,"text":"Wavetel A2Z Gold"},{"id":40,"text":"mysql test2"},{"id":63,"text":"inbound test"},{"id":137,"text":"testpbxretail"},{"id":144,"text":"INBOUND CLI"},{"id":145,"text":"0800142324"},{"id":164,"text":"Rategenerator-Otto-Test"},{"id":165,"text":"Rategenerator-Otto-Test 2 "},{"id":166,"text":"Rategenerator-Otto-Test 3 "},{"id":171,"text":"VasimRateGenerator"}]
```

I want shortest way to use first element value(19) as a key of second element(instead of 'text') there are multiple elements so it can be done via loop. and remove first element after that.

so i want output like below (e.g. for first element [{"id":19,"text":"A-Z CLI 19/03/2015"}]):

```js
[{"19":"A-Z CLI 19/03/2015"}]
```

Comment: There's no such thing (reliably, anyway) as the "first" property of an object.

Comment: you cannot do this in the JSON string itself, it is not a dynamic value representation system. All your JSON data is in your string, without external reference. Anyhow, you need to parse your JSON to Javascript objects to achieve that

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` method  by passing a `callback` function as argument.

```js
let arr = [{"id":19,"text":"A-Z CLI 19/03/2015"},{"id":36,"text":"Wavetel Retail1"},{"id":37,"text":"Wavetel A2Z Platinum"},{"id":38,"text":"Wavetel A2Z Gold"},{"id":40,"text":"mysql test2"},{"id":63,"text":"inbound test"},{"id":137,"text":"testpbxretail"},{"id":144,"text":"INBOUND CLI"},{"id":145,"text":"0800142324"},{"id":164,"text":"Rategenerator-Otto-Test"},{"id":165,"text":"Rategenerator-Otto-Test 2 "},{"id":166,"text":"Rategenerator-Otto-Test 3 "},{"id":171,"text":"VasimRateGenerator"}]

arr = arr.map(function({id, text}){
    return { [id]: text };
});
console.log(arr);
```

or just use one `arrow` function.

```js
let arr = [{"id":19,"text":"A-Z CLI 19/03/2015"},{"id":36,"text":"Wavetel Retail1"},{"id":37,"text":"Wavetel A2Z Platinum"},{"id":38,"text":"Wavetel A2Z Gold"},{"id":40,"text":"mysql test2"},{"id":63,"text":"inbound test"},{"id":137,"text":"testpbxretail"},{"id":144,"text":"INBOUND CLI"},{"id":145,"text":"0800142324"},{"id":164,"text":"Rategenerator-Otto-Test"},{"id":165,"text":"Rategenerator-Otto-Test 2 "},{"id":166,"text":"Rategenerator-Otto-Test 3 "},{"id":171,"text":"VasimRateGenerator"}]

arr = arr.map(({id, text}) =>  ({[id]: text}));
console.log(arr);
```